# Can I reduce the pixel size on my VNC window?

Tags: lubuntu, vnc

A little hard to explain this, but I am wondering if I can create a miniature VNC window so that it's less visible to people looking over my shoulder.  Ideally, this would retain the same pixel size but act much like my Android screen does when I'm using VNC on it...only this would be on the PC, Lubuntu 12.04.

I know I can shrink the window size and scroll to the right or left.  But the text and images within the window are still the same size.  I would like to have everything smaller...as if it's been shrunk by 2/3rds.

Thank you and again, apologies for the vagueness of this question...I don't exactly know how to describe it well.

Comment: What VNC client are you using? you can certainly do that with remmina (scaled mode) and with the TightVNC viewer on Windows.

Comment: @steeldriver, I am using RealVNC on windows to access a Lubuntu Tightvnc-based server.  What option should I be looking for in the Tightvnc client?  (And thank you for the response!)

Comment: You should probably be looking for an option in the RealVNC viewer like 'Options --> Display --> Scale to window size'

Comment: Bingo!  Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for!  THANK YOU!